# Надо ли закавычивать "не"?

Tags: кавычки

*Я бы хотел добавить еще одно не. Он не изолированный.*
Надо ли закавычивать первое *не*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово НЕ нужно выделить **кавычками или курсивом**:

Я бы хотел добавить еще одно (слово) "не".

Или: Я бы хотел добавить еще одно *не*.

**Примечание**

По такому же образцу строятся предложения со словом НО, однако в этом случае НО отмечено в словарной статье как самостоятельное сущ. ср. рода, поэтому кавычки не ставятся.

**Но, неизм.**; ср. Обстоятельство, мешающее чему-л., препятствие; возражение. *Есть маленькое но. Никаких но - выполняйте задание. Давайте без всяких но. Без но не получится. В этом деле очень много но.*